# Translation of IT terms like close, next, search, etc

Tags: translation

I need to translate a lot of terms in a IT-Application like buttons:

```
close
next
exit
search
etc...
```

Can anyone translate these or is there any site with a list of common terms for Italian? I'm not searching a generic translation, but technical IT terminology.

Comment: There is such a list. It is called “dictionary”. This is not a free translation site; please look at its description.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was on this site, but I don't find the list. Do you have a hint or a link ?

Comment: @user1344545 [wordreference](http://wordreference.com) is a great free online dictionary

Comment: @user1344545 First of all you spelled Italian wrong. Second of all, you can use google translater ( link below) or you could look it up in the Italian dictionary.                   Here is the link for google translater - https://translate.google.com/m/translate

Comment: Sorry to all. Thats not what I am looking for. Of course I could google and I will find GoogleTranslate (Tia27 ?!?) and other online translations. But in case of my question, these are Information technologies (IT) termologies, which should be translated exacly. For example close can be translated in 10 different variants, but you will see close in a italien application always be translated as the same.

Comment: I do not see a reason for closing, the request is valid and well defined. I do not second the "generic dictionary" suggestion, many computer terms have a "crystallized" translation that may differ from more "everyday usage" counterpart. Microsoft [provides their official dictionary](http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Default.aspx) to translate technical, UI-related terms, I'd take that one as a starting point.

Comment: :-) I hope its fine now. You see I am not an italien.

Comment: @Matteo Italia. Thank you very much. I guess this is the right place to start. Have a good weekend. I will tell if it helped.

Comment: @Matteo. Thats exact what I looked for. You can give the answer with the Link to the Microsoft Site and I would accept if you like. kind regards

Comment: @user1344545: unfortunately, the question is still closed, so I cannot post it as an answer, I'll post it ASAP.

Comment: He asked for a IT glossary in italian, it's not just translation.

Something like this: http://www.proz.com/glossary-translations/english-to-italian-translations/68

Comment: user1344545 and @MatteoItalia, I reopened the question. Please make sure that the answers [don't just link to a single source](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/82/answers-consisting-only-of-a-quote), but provide a clear but concise explanation of the rules used for translations in the IT context. Thanks.

Comment: Having worked in localisation, there are other factors to consider than just translation. What is the context? Are there any string length constraints?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways you can do that.

1. Most universal approach is [Microsoft Language Portal](http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Default.aspx). You can find translations of those words, find in which Microsoft projects it used and description of it. It is quite handy.
2. You can use [Multilingual App Toolkit](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/multilingual-app-toolkit). It is targeting Windows application, however you can use it for any projects. Visit a website for more info. If you have any difficulties leave a comment and I will try to enhance my answer.
3. Another option is to use [Microsoft Translator Hub](https://hub.microsofttranslator.com/). I recommend this if you have to translate a large project and have a consistency.
4. Next my recommendation is to use [Google Translator Toolkit](https://translate.google.com/toolkit/). However I am not sure that there is a way to set subject or target as IT.

Comment: Google Translator Toolkit is an effective collaborative translation platform, but there is no way to set IT as the domain.

Answer (score 0):

google translate is helpful but does not always catch the context. my advice is to set up language pack on windows or just switch to italian if on ubuntu and reverse engineer. the heavy lifting is already done for you.

close -> chuidi. next -> prossimo or avanti (next, forward). backward -> indietro. exit -> esci. search -> cerca.

cheers -> saluti.